# No se porque el programa se paró cuando eso no era mi intención

Tags: python

En el dibujo (fragmento de código) es donde se para, pero yo quería que se parase más tarde, ¿alguien sabe porque se paró? Esto es lo que se ha intentado:

```
import random

print('Haig de fer un examen que no en tinc ni idea de què sortirà, així que faré les preguntes sense ni llegir-les')
print('Cada pregunta té quatre opcions, per un encert suma 1 i cada una equivocada resta 0,33')
print('''quantes preguntes té l'examen?(0 per acabar)''')

p1 = int(input())
nota = 0
p = 0
while p1 > 0:
    while p < p1:
        x = random.randint(1, 4)
        if x == 1:
            nota = nota + 1
            p = p + 1
        else:
            nota = nota - 0.33
            p = p + 1
print()
nota10 = nota / p1 * 10
print('En aquest exàmen de ', p1, ' preguntes has tret la fantàstica nota de ', nota10,)
```

Comment: Hola, estás en el sitio en español. Por favor, [edit] y traduce toda tu pregunta. Luego, Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes. Todo va como texto, código y mensajes de error.

Comment: ¿Podrías copiar el código en la pregunta en vez de subir una captura de imagen? Para poder facilitar que el resto te ayudemos.

Comment: Como te han dicho, lee [ask]. Pon en el título el problema _específico_ que estás teniendo, y el código _como texto, con formato_ (no todos podemos ver las imágenes, y mucho menos, puede hacerse _copypaste_ de una imagen) :) Recuerda que el código en los comentarios es ilegible: pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta.

Comment: perdon es que no se como hacer-lo para que sea suficiente bien para que los otros lo entenden

Comment: Se te queda atascado entre los dos whiles, se cumple la primera condición pero no la segunda, entonces como la segunda no se cumple, entra en un bucle infinito. Con eso ya respondo a tu pregunta. Si quieres que te ayudemos en qué hacer para solucionarlo, comenta qué es lo que quieres hacer o cual es tu objetivo.

Comment: Ten presente que si no te molestas en redactar bien tu pregunta, cumplir con las especificaciones de [ask], incluir (si es posible) un [mcve], ¿por qué debería algún miembro de la comunidad en molestarse en ayudarte?

Comment: Facilitaria ayudarte si el programa estuviera escrito en español.

Comment: @RosaZheng No es que se pare, al contrario, no deja de correr, porque has puesto esto:  `while p1>0:` pero luego no varias el valor de `p1` en ningún momento y por lo tanto nunca sale del bucle, siempre es mayor que 0, a pesar que internamente ya haya terminado con el otro while.

Comment: Tienes un error en el primer while ya que la variable P1 no cambia el valor con lo cual crea un bucle infinito. Entiendo que ese while realmente sería un if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu primer bucle `while p1 > 0:` es un bucle infinito (no acaba nunca, o acabará con un error de memoria si se llena).
esto es porque no le has puesto ninguna condición para salir del bucle diferente a `p1 > 0` y dentro de tu bucle nunca cambias el valor de `p1`.

No entiendo los textos que has puesto pero quiero pensar que tu idea era recoger ese bucle **n** veces, siendo n el valor que tienes en `p1`.

Para ello puedes reducir el valor de `p1` a cada pasada del bucle, pero ten en cuenta que tu while tiene que cambiarse a `(p1 - 1)`:

```
while (p1 - 1) > 0:
    while p < p1:
        x = random.randint(1, 4)
        if x == 1:
            nota = nota + 1
            p = p + 1
        else:
            nota = nota - 0.33
            p = p + 1
    p1 -= 1
```

o como alternativa (y en mi opinión seria las "más" correcta) deberías cambiar el primer `while` por un `for` porque desde el momento inicial tu ya sabes cuantas veces quieres ejecutar tu bucle.
Y la variable `p` no haría falta porque realmente solo la has creado para saber por qué pregunta vas (o no?)

```
import random

print('Haig de fer un examen que no en tinc ni idea de què sortirà, així que faré les preguntes sense ni llegir-les')
print('Cada pregunta té quatre opcions, per un encert suma 1 i cada una equivocada resta 0,33')
print('''quantes preguntes té l'examen?(0 per acabar)''')

p1 = int(input())
nota = 0
for n in range(p1):
    x = random.randint(1, 4)
    if x == 1:
        nota += 1
    else:
        nota -= 0.33
print()
nota10 = nota / p1 * 10
print('En aquest exàmen de ', p1, ' preguntes has tret la fantàstica nota de ', nota10)
```